# Boolean doesn't return right value

Tags: java, swing

I have been working on this for two days and i still can't figure it out.
So i have these classes:

- MyContentPane
- ParametersPanel
- ControlsPanel

The first class looks like this:

```
public class MyContentPane extends JPanel{

private ParametersPanel parametersPanel;
private ControlsPanel controlPanel;
private CashRegistersPanel cashRegistersPanel;

public MyContentPane() {

    parametersPanel = new ParametersPanel();
    controlPanel = new ControlsPanel(parametersPanel);
    cashRegistersPanel = new CashRegistersPanel();

    this.setLayout(null);
    this.add(controlPanel);
    this.add(parametersPanel);
    this.add(cashRegistersPanel);

    controlPanel.setBounds(0, 0, 300, 250);
    parametersPanel.setBounds(0, 250, 300, 450);
    cashRegistersPanel.setBounds(300, 0, 1500, 700);

    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1800,700));

}
```

}

The second class looks like this :

```
public class ParametersPanel extends JPanel{

private ControlsPanel controlsPanel;

private JButton reset;

public ParametersPanel() {

    controlsPanel = new ControlsPanel(this);


    this.setBackground(new Color(219,221,255));

    reset       = new JButton("Reset parameters");

    reset.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 14));

    this.setLayout(null);


    this.add(reset);

    reset.setBounds(10, 245, 280, 30);



    reset.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            boolean startIsPressed = controlsPanel.StartisPressed();
            System.out.println("Boolean: " + startIsPressed);
        }
    });

}
```

The last class is:

```
public class ControlsPanel extends JPanel{

private JButton start;
private JButton stop;

private boolean startIsPressed;

public ControlsPanel(final ParametersPanel panel) {

    start       = new JButton("Start");
    stop        = new JButton("Stop");

    start.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 14));
    stop.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 14));

    this.setLayout(null);
    this.setBackground(new Color(199,202,255));

    this.add(start);
    this.add(stop);


    start.setBounds(10, 10, 280, 30);
    stop.setBounds(10, 50, 280, 30);

    stop.setEnabled(false);


    start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        if (start.getText().equals("Start")) {
            start.setText("Pause");
            stop.setEnabled(true);
            startIsPressed = true;

            System.out.println("Start Button boolean value: " + startIsPressed + stringStartIsPressed);

        }
    });

public boolean StartisPressed() {
    return startIsPressed;
}
```

Now the problem is that once I press the Start button in the ControlsPanel, the value of the boolean turns in to true. But when i ask the value of this boolean in the ParametersPanel by pressing the reset button, it returns false. I found out that if i change the order of the panel decleration in the first class (MyContentPane), i solve the problem, but then i can't ask for booleans in the ControlsPanel...

**Added another class**

```
public class CashRegistersPanel extends JPanel{

private Image img;
private int amount;
private ParametersPanel parametersPanel;
private ControlsPanel controlsPanel;
private boolean startIsPressed;

public CashRegistersPanel() {

    parametersPanel = new ParametersPanel();

    startIsPressed = controlsPanel.StartisPressed();

    this.setBackground(new Color(237,237,237));
    this.setLayout(null);

    CashRegister cashRegister = new CashRegister();
    img = cashRegister.getImg();

    amount = parametersPanel.getAmountOfRegisters();


}
    public void setControlsPanel(ControlsPanel cp) {
    controlsPanel = cp;

}
```

I changed the MyContentPane as you guys suggested and added something more:

```
public class MyContentPane extends JPanel{

private ParametersPanel parametersPanel;
private ControlsPanel controlPanel;
private CashRegistersPanel cashRegistersPanel;

public MyContentPane() {

    parametersPanel = new ParametersPanel();
    controlPanel = new ControlsPanel(parametersPanel);
    parametersPanel.setControlsPanel(controlPanel);
    cashRegistersPanel = new CashRegistersPanel(parametersPanel, controlPanel);
```

Thank you guys, question solved!

Answer (score 3):

You're creating 2 `ControlsPanel`'s.

The one in ParametersPanel should not be made, this is the offending line:

```
controlsPanel = new ControlsPanel(this);
```

Instead, create a setter method on ParametersPanel:

```
public void setControlsPanel(ControlsPanel cp) {
    controlsPanel = cp;
}
```

And change the initialization in the first class to:

```
parametersPanel = new ParametersPanel();
controlPanel = new ControlsPanel(parametersPanel);
parametersPanel.setControlsPanel(controlPanel); // <- new line
cashRegistersPanel = new CashRegistersPanel();
```

Comment: This really helped me so thank you for that, but I tried the same for my CashRegisterpanel but that didn't help. Do you mind looking at that as well?

Comment: Oh never mind! I just added in MyContentPane in CahRegisterPanel(ParametersPanel,controlPanel). Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like in `MyContentPane` you instantiate a `ControlsPanel`, but then the `ParametersPanel` makes its own `ControlsPanel`.  I would think you should pass the `ControlsPanel` to the `ParametersPanel` instead of creating a new one.  Keep in mind that every time you say `new` you create a completely separate object.

change this:

```
public ParametersPanel() {

    controlsPanel = new ControlsPanel(this);
```

to this:

```
public ParametersPanel(ControlPanel cp) {

    controlsPanel = cp;
```

and change the MyControlPanel code to:

```
controlPanel = new ControlsPanel();
parametersPanel = new ParametersPanel(controlPanel);
```

and the ControlsPanel constructor to:

```
public ControlsPanel() {
```

since you don't seem to be using the reference to the `ParametersPanel`.

Alternately, you could set `startIsPressed` as a static variable, but I don't think that is what you really want.